# glass shader that doesn't show the back of the object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I´m making a cell material for a character. I´ve been trying some combinations and I got one that uses a glass and transparent shader mix (transparent shader to let more light pass and give it a better look).

It doesn´t look bad but I want to get rid of a weird looking thing in the back of the model.

As you can see in the picture at the top, if you look at the back of it you can see that there is a part with darker color. That´s what I want to remove.

At the bottom part it´s a screenshot of the material. It looks very simple but that´s because it´s the first test.

Can you help me to get rid of the weird part I´ve explained or tell me why is it there? Thanks.

[image: Render and material]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way how to do it is use **backfacing** as a factor. This node setup will remove faces on back of your character.

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> -> *Input* -> *Geometry*

[image: backfacing]